# Comma separated string parameter filter in Where clause My SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, stored-procedures, mysql-python

I'm trying to filter the records with where clause in procedure based on IN input parameter values I had written the stored procedure in My SQL as like below :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_get_logs_Test`(IN `p_Bot_Ids` VARCHAR(500))
    NO SQL
select id, bot_id, log_level,log_type,time_stamp,finger_print,windows_identity,machine_name,process_name,process_version
,job_Id,robot_name,machine_Id,file_name,message,created_date from log
where id < 200 and
bot_id IN (p_Bot_Ids)$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My "p_Bot_Ids" is a comma separated string. If I pass "1,2" its filtering only with "1". if I pass "2,1" its filtering with only "2".

Also my "p_Bot_Ids" can also be null.In that case I needs to pull out all the records.

Let us consider there are 50 records in my table. If i pass "p_Bot_Ids" = "1,2,3" I needs to get only 1,2,3  Ids records(total 3 rows) only. 
If I pass "p_Bot_Ids" = NULL then I should get all my 50 records.

Answer (score 1):

What you are passing to the procedure is not a list: it is a comma-separated list, in other words a scalar value. So `IN` does not do what you expect: it actually checks if `bot_id` is equal to the parameter (this includes implicit conversion to the correct datatype).

If you are to keep the parameter as such, then one option is to use [string function `find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead: its purpose is to search for a value in a comma-separated list.

```
where id < 200 and find_in_set(bot_id, p_Bot_Ids)
```

If you want to match on `null` values too, then:

```
where id < 200 
and (
    (bot_id  is null and p_Bot_Ids is null)
    or find_in_set(bot_id, p_Bot_Ids)
)
```

Comment: If I pass NULL value to p_Bot_Ids,Its giving 0 records. But working with values.

Comment: @SrikanthReddy: how do you want to handle `NULL` values? If the parameter is null, do you want to select rows where `bot_id` is `NULL`?

Comment: @SrikanthReddy: I updated my answer to handle `null` values.

Comment: If I pass Null to parameter I don't want to consider the parameter. i need to fetch all the records irrespective of filtering with "p_Bot_Ids". If I pass value to parameter needs to filter, This case is working as you said.

Comment: Edited the question with example of need. Please check once. For NULL case.